# How to get search autocomplete in Google Places API for Android only by specific region type (country, sublocality etc.)?

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm trying to create autocomplete searching in my Android app via Google Places API for Android. Main goal is to search only by **cities** and **administrative_area_level_1**, but unfortunately I can't find way to create such [AutocompleteFilter](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter). Maybe someone had the same problem?

I'm using Play Services ver. 9.8.0

Comment: Please follow [https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete). Country wise and location-wise filter is mentioned in that document.

Comment: @Danieboy 
I tried to use new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
        .setFilterType(Place.TYPE_ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1)
        .build();
but it's not changing the result

Comment: @Kunu I don't need to get result from specific country, as new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
        .setCountry("UA")
        .build();
I want find possibility to get from Places API only selected region type such as country, locality or administrative_area_level_1

Answer (score 0):

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components=country:IN");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single filter that does exactly what you want, unfortunately. `AutocompleteFilter` allows you to specify [`TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.html#TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS) or [`TYPE_FILTER_CITIES`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.html#TYPE_FILTER_CITIES) but these can't be combined in a single filter. Also, `TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS` can return things other than `administrative_area_level_1`.

One solution might be to make two autocomplete request in parallel with the two different filter settings and combine the results.

Comment: Thank you! I understand. But if I combine this two filters, I'll receive many "waste" data (other no needed region types), which I couldn't replace by my target data.